# Union A|B of types + overlapping member of different type. Conflict resolution logic

Tags: typescript

We have:

```ts
// 1 case - conflict number VS boolean

type A2 = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

type B2 = {
  y: boolean; // conflict
  z: number;
};

type U2 = A2 | B2;

let u2: U2;

u2 = { x: 1, y: 1 };
u2 = { y: false, z: 5 };

u2 = { x: 1, y: false, z: 3 }; // error
u2 = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }; // error

// 2 case - conflict number VS string

type A = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

type B = {
  y: string; // conflict
  z: number;
};

type U = A | B;

let u: U;

u = { x: 1, y: 2 };
u = { y: "2", z: 3 };

u = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }; // ok. why?
u = { x: 1, y: "2", z: 3 }; // ok. why?
```

i'm ok with error logic in case #1 - union of types `U2` makes values possess properties of type `A2` or of type `B2`, or of both (but in our concrete case we have type conflict for `y`, so "both" is not working here, we can't have `y` in value at all).

**Question**: why case #2 is ok? why it does not follow the same logic and `y` is not being excluded, what am i missing here? is there any document, PR that describes this case 1 vs 2 difference? I'm using TS 4.7. thanks.

Comment: Well, logically `A | B` means that the variable can be **either** `A` **or** `B`. In case #1 you are assigning properties from `A` **and** `B`, which produces an error. In case #2 you are only assigning properties from `A` **or** `B`.

Comment: @MikeS. I don't see what you are saying here. To see, both case #1 and case #2 look identical except that `string` is used instead of `boolean`.

Comment: Good point ;) It seems to me as if in case #1 Typescript is able to infer a type from the union based on the assignment. complaining that either `x` or `z` isn't in one of the types. In case #2, it seems Typescript cannot infer a type and just says it's valid (which is technically true, since both assignments are **assignable** to the union type, meaning they contain either `x` and `y` or `y` and `z`).